# plotly: Updating data with dropdown selection

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am not sure if this is possible, but here is what I would like to do. I would like to update the data in a `plotly` plot by selecting from a dropdown menu.

As a simple example, let's assume I have a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(200), y = runif(200), z = runif(200))
```

from which I use `df$x` and `df$y` in a scatter plot. Two scenarios of data manipulation I would like to achieve using a dropdown:

1. Replace `df$y` with `df$z`
2. Plot only the first `n` values of `df$x` and `df$y`

I looked at the following two examples, which I can easily reproduce:
https://plot.ly/r/dropdowns/

However, I have no idea how to pass the information regarding the data to be plotted based on the dropdown selection. For scenario 2 e.g. I have tried it with `args = list("data", df[1:n,])` which did not work.

For scenario 1 the (only?) way to go (according to the examples) seems to be hiding/showing the traces respectively. Is that the only way for scenario 2 as well?

Any alternative ideas?

**Update 1:** Add reproducible example

So here is an example which achieve what I would like in scenario 1.

```
require(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(200), y = runif(200), z = runif(200))
Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="xxx") #actual credentials replaced
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="xxx") #actual credentials replaced

p <- plot_ly(df, x = df$x, y = df$y, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
  add_trace(mode = "markers", y = df$z, name = "B", visible = T) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
    xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE)),
               label = "Show All"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "Show A"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
               label = "Show B")))
    ))

plotly_POST(p)
```

Result here: https://plot.ly/~spietrzyk/96/drop-down-menus-styling/
This is based on the example from https://plot.ly/r/dropdowns/

However, I am wondering if one could pass the data to be plotted instead of triggering changes to the `visible` property of individual traces.

The one thing I tried was the following:

```
p <- plot_ly(df, x = df$x, y = df$y, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
    xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("y", df$y),
               label = "Show A"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("y", df$z),
               label = "Show B")))
))
```

Result here: https://plot.ly/~spietrzyk/98/drop-down-menus-styling/
This approach cannot work, as the data from `df$z` is not posted to the grid (https://plot.ly/~spietrzyk/99/).

So I was wondering is there anyway to manipulate the data to be plotted based on dropdown selection, beyond plotting all traces and than switching the `visible` property by dropdown selections.

Comment: Please try to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing us exactly what your code was doing. It's not clear how you were invoking `plotly` or even where you stuck those args. This will make it easier to help you.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not too familiar with the R API so my comment might be of limited usefulness, but this is a feature in active development. You can pass data directly through the updatemenus command, but there's also a new `frame` concept to facilitate this. The `animation` docs for `plotly.js` have some examples: https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/#defining-named-frames-with-plotlyaddframes Unfortunately, I don't know if frames are accessible through R API yet (see: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1014 ), which is why this is perhaps not a fully satisfying answer.

Comment: And FWIW, here's a slightly less ambitious example that passes data directly through the updatemenus commands: http://codepen.io/rsreusser/pen/mAjpkb?editors=0010 Again, apologies that it's not via the R API.

Comment: Which plotly version do you use? For me it is working like a charme with the newest version `plotly_4.5.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was still on an older version of plotly. But even updating the package, the example above does not work for me). Did you replicate the example which contains the line `args = list("y", df$y)`?

Answer (score 10):

Is this what you were after?

```
require(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(200), y = runif(200), z = runif(200))
p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
layout(
  title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
  xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
  yaxis = list(title = "y"),
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      y = 0.7,
      buttons = list(
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("y", list(df$y)),  # put it in a list
             label = "Show A"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list("y", list(df$z)),  # put it in a list
             label = "Show B")))
))
p
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this example handle a list of length that is determined by the dataframe, not hardcoded as a list for each list item?

Comment: @jimmy G i have a similary question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556896/how-to-return-a-datatable-updated-by-2-dropdowns-as-inputs-in-plotly-python, 
if you are free, please drop by and have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

On the top of @jimmy G's answer.

You can automatically create the buttons so that you don't have to manually specify every single variable you want in the plot.

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(200), y = runif(200), z = runif(200), j = runif(200), k = rep(0.7, 200), i = rnorm(200,0.6,0.05))

create_buttons <- function(df, y_axis_var_names) {
  lapply(
    y_axis_var_names,
    FUN = function(var_name, df) {
      button <- list(
        method = 'restyle',
        args = list('y', list(df[, var_name])),
        label = sprintf('Show %s', var_name)
      )
    },
    df
  )
  
}

y_axis_var_names <- c('y', 'z', 'j', 'k', 'i')

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
     layout(
         title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
         xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"),
         updatemenus = list(
             list(
                 y = 0.7,
                 buttons = create_buttons(df, y_axis_var_names)
             )
         ))
p
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Most useful indeed! As an addition, multiple data attributes can be added in the `arg` function as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69364462/8076560