# Dropdown menu to select x, y and color (plotly)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to create a plotly graph with selectable x, y and color variables, based in part on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024029/plotly-updating-data-with-dropdown-selection). The x and y variable selection appears to work, however when new x and y variables are selected, the point color is lost.

Further, I have tried to use a similar strategy to select the point colour, but unfortunately this does not seem to work.

Another option would be to use the "set visible" strategy in the previously linked question.

**Example:**

```
library(plotly)
library(pcaMethods)

pca <- pcaMethods::pca(mtcars, nPcs=3)

df <- as.data.frame(pca@scores)

colors1 <- sample(c("red", "green", "blue"), nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
colors2 <- sample(c("red", "green", "blue"), nrow(df), replace=TRUE)

p <- plotly::plot_ly(df, x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2, type = "scatter",
    color = sample(c("red", "green", "blue"), nrow(df), replace=TRUE),
    mode = "markers") 

p <-  plotly::layout(
    p,
    title = "Dropdown PCA plot",
    updatemenus = list(
        list(
            y = 0.7,
            buttons = list(
                list(method = "restyle",
                   args = list(
                    "x", list(df$PC1)
                    ),
                   label = "PC1"),
                list(method = "restyle",
                   args = list(
                    "x", list(df$PC2)
                    ),
                   label = "PC2"),
                list(method = "restyle",
                   args = list(
                    "x", list(df$PC3)
                    ),
                   label = "PC3")
                )
            ),
        list(
            y = 0.5,
            buttons = list(
                list(method = "restyle",
                   args = list(
                    "y", list(df$PC1)
                    ),
                   label = "PC1"),
                list(method = "restyle",
                   args = list(
                    "y", list(df$PC2)
                    ),
                   label = "PC2"),
                list(method = "restyle",
                   args = list(
                    "y", list(df$PC3)
                    ),
                   label = "PC3")
                )
            )
        )
    )

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, "test.html", selfcontained=FALSE)
```

Comment: Downvotes without feedback are not helpful

Comment: Hi @aocall — I think I'm trying to do a similar thing as you were in this question. Did you ever figure out how to enable selecting which variable to color points by? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790759/plotly-select-variable-mapped-to-color-from-dropdown-menu

Comment: Yes, but I made a custom HTMLwidget rather than using the standard plotly R API.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response!

Comment: The author is not looking to use Shiny dropdowns, it looks like, but for those who land here that are using Shiny, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076025/r-shiny-plotly-change-color-of-a-trace-with-javascript-without-affecting-mar/67612384#67612384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible in the R API, as mapping from variables to plot output is done on the R side, not by plotly.js.

This is explained at the following link: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/803

This functionality can be accomplished using plotly.js and HTML. One would have to add `select` elements to a HTML page, and add event listeners to call `Plotly.newPlot()` on update.

An example implementation can be seen here: https://github.com/Alanocallaghan/plotlyutils/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/selectable_scatter_plot/selectable_scatter_plot.js

Answer (score 0):

Picking this up very late but I've recently had the same query and this still isn't possible in R. I created a bare bones function that generates a series of scatter plots using plotly to compare columns in an input dataframe and added a dropdown menu for the user to select different comparisons.

Here's the function:

```
#' Use interactive scatter plots to compare distributions using plotly
#'
#' For each column provided function will plot a comparison scatter plot and
#' use a dropdown menu for user to select different comparisons
#' @param distributions dataframe of distributions to plot
#' @param title_prefix prefix to use in each scatter plot title
#' @param caption_x x position of caption. Defaults to 1 (right).
#' @param caption_y y position of caption. Defaults to -0.1 (bottom).
compare_distributions_scatter <- function(
    distributions,
    title_prefix,
    dropdown_x = 1.25, dropdown_y = 3.8
) {
  # Initialise a plotly plot
  scatter <- plot_ly()
  
  # Note possible comparisons of columns to compare
  column_names <- colnames(distributions)
  combinations <- combn(column_names, m = 2)
  n_combinations <- length(combinations)

  # Initialise a nested list structure to create settings for comparison plots
  dropdown_button_info <- list()
  
  # Examine each combination
  for (index in seq_len(ncol(combinations))) {
    ## Creating comparison plot
    
    # Get data source names
    x_source <- combinations[1, index]
    y_source <- combinations[2, index]
    
    # Get X and Y values
    x_values <- distributions[, x_source]
    y_values <- distributions[, y_source]

    # Add plot comparing two current distributions
    scatter <- scatter %>% add_trace(
      x = x_values, y = y_values,
      type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
      marker = list(color = "black", opacity = 0.75),
      visible = index == 1
    )

    ## Adding to button info
    
    # Build visibility values vector
    visibility <- rep(FALSE, n_combinations)
    visibility[index] <- TRUE
    
    # Add dropdown button info for current comparison plot
    dropdown_button_info[[index]] <- list(
      label = paste0(x_source, "-", y_source),
      method = "update",
      args = list(
        list(visible = visibility),
        list(
          title = paste0(
            title_prefix, " from ", x_source, " and ", y_source
          ),
          xaxis = list(title = x_source),
          yaxis = list(title = y_source)
        )
      )
    )
  }
  
  # Set initial plotting title
  scatter <- scatter %>%
    layout(
      title = paste0(
        title_prefix, " from ", column_names[1], " and ", column_names[2]
      ),
      xaxis = list(title = column_names[1]),
      yaxis = list(title = column_names[2]),
      showlegend = FALSE
    )

  # Add buttons to switch between comparisons
  scatter <- scatter %>% layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(x = dropdown_x, y = dropdown_y, buttons = dropdown_button_info)
    )
  )

  # Show plot
  scatter
}
```

With the above function you could create your comparison plots with:

```
compare_distributions_scatter(
  distributions = mtcars[, c("mpg", "disp", "drat", "qsec")],
  title_prefix = "Comparing car info"
)
```

Generating:
[image]