# R Plotly dropdown variable selection with color

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, plotly.js

This question is related to some others on SO but I haven't found a solution yet.

I'm looking to use `plotly`'s [dropdown functionality](https://plotly.com/r/dropdowns/) to select which variable gets plotted on the x-axis, similar to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024029/plotly-updating-data-with-dropdown-selection?noredirect=1&lq=1#_=_) that's been super helpful in getting me to where I am now.

I'm now trying to use the `color` argument in `plot_ly` to color the markers in my plot. However, when I use the dropdown to change the x-variable, it seems like the data gets jumbled or mixed up. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, 
        type ="scatter", mode = "markers",text = ~Species,
        hovertemplate = paste('<i>Species</i>: %{text}',
                        '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                        '<b>Y</b>: %{y}')
        
        ) %>%
  layout(
    annotations = list(
      list(
        text = "<b>X-Axis Variable:</b>", x=0.05, y=1.13, 
        xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
      )
    ),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = "list",
        x = 0.25,
        xanchor = "left",
        y = 1.15,
        buttons = list(
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x = list(iris$Sepal.Length)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Length"))),
            label = "Sepal.Length"
          ),
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x =list(iris$Sepal.Width)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Width"))),
            label = "Sepal.Width"
          ),
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x = list(iris$Petal.Length)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Petal.Length"))),
            label = "Petal.Length"
          ),
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x = list(iris$Petal.Width)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Petal.Width"))),
            label = "Petal.Width"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Which produces a plot that initially *looks* correct but its behavior is not correct:
[image: initial image from code example]

We know it's not correct because when we change the x-variable to `Sepal.Width`, which is the same as the y-variable and therefore should result in a simple line of points along the y=x axis, we're left with the plot below:
[image: plot showing error in where points are located]

There's some talk on SO from [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719220/dropdown-menu-to-select-x-y-and-color-plotly?noredirect=1&lq=1) that suggests that *selecting* a color variable isn't supported with the R-plotly API but I'm not interested in changing the color. Interestingly, this issue disappears when I remove the `color = ~Species` argument from my plot.

Thanks all - not sure where the best place to look is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to hopefully help someone else out some point in the future.

As long as you're not interested in a legend, you can actually get around this data plotting issue by mapping the color to the points in the `marker` argument of `plot_ly()`.

```
library(plotly)
iris2 <- mutate(iris, iris.col = factor(Species, label = c("red", "blue", "green")))

plot_ly(data = iris2, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, marker = list(color = ~iris.col), type ="scatter", mode = "markers",text = ~Species,
        hovertemplate = paste('<i>Species</i>: %{text}',
                        '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                        '<b>Y</b>: %{y}')
        
        ) %>%
  layout(
    annotations = list(
      list(
        text = "<b>X-Axis Variable:</b>", x=0.05, y=1.13, xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
      )
    ),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = "list",
        x = 0.25,
        xanchor = "left",
        y = 1.15,
        buttons = list(
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x = list(iris$Sepal.Length)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Length"))),
            label = "Sepal.Length"
          ),
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x =list(iris$Sepal.Width)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Width"))),
            label = "Sepal.Width"
          ),
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x = list(iris$Petal.Length)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Petal.Length"))),
            label = "Petal.Length"
          ),
          list(
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(x = list(iris$Petal.Width)),
                        list(xaxis = list(title = "Petal.Width"))),
            label = "Petal.Width"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

With the expected output:
[image]