# Plotly: Update Several Data Attributes in an Argument with R

Tags: r, r-plotly

This is a question following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385494/8076560) by @klopetx. I have searched for how to update *several* data attributes in a single arg in Plotly in the [official docs](https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/). It is possible in Python and thus also Javascript. For reproducibility, I have copied the code example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385494/8076560).

For the example, I would like to make the `args = list('y', list(df[, var_name]))` also include the `x`. I imagined to this via the following:

```
args = list('y', list(df[, var_name]),'x', list(df[, var_name]))
```

Added to the code example, this would be:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(200), y = runif(200), z = runif(200), j = runif(200), k = rep(0.7, 200), i = rnorm(200,0.6,0.05))

create_buttons <- function(df, y_axis_var_names) {
  lapply(
    y_axis_var_names,
    FUN = function(var_name, df) {
      button <- list(
        method = 'restyle',
        # args = list('y', list(df[, var_name])), #previous example for only one attribute
        args = list('y', list(df[, var_name]),'x', list(df[, var_name])), #new code which doesn't work
        label = sprintf('Show %s', var_name)
      )
    },
    df
  )
  
}

y_axis_var_names <- c('y', 'z', 'j', 'k', 'i')

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
     layout(
         title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
         xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"),
         updatemenus = list(
             list(
                 y = 0.7,
                 buttons = create_buttons(df, y_axis_var_names)
             )
         ))
p
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution comes from this [answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-r-modify-several-attributes-from-a-single-restyle-button/39841/2?u=sajdfhsfni345): just wrap the attributes in an additional `list()`. Of course this is straight forward but it was not intuitive for me.

Now the example works with the new `arg` line which allows for multiple attributes to now be added.

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(200), y = runif(200), z = runif(200), j = runif(200), k = rep(0.7, 200), i = rnorm(200,0.6,0.05))

create_buttons <- function(df, y_axis_var_names) {
  lapply(
    y_axis_var_names,
    FUN = function(var_name, df) {
      button <- list(
        method = 'restyle',
        # args = list('y', list(df[, var_name])), #previous example for only one attribute
        # args = list('y', list(df[, var_name]),'x', list(df[, var_name])), #new code which didn't work
        args = list(list(y = list(df[, var_name]),x = list(df[, var_name]))), # working code! 
        label = sprintf('Show %s', var_name)
      )
    },
    df
  )

}

y_axis_var_names <- c('y', 'z', 'j', 'k', 'i')

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
     layout(
         title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
         xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"),
         updatemenus = list(
             list(
                 y = 0.7,
                 buttons = create_buttons(df, y_axis_var_names)
             )
         ))
p
```