# Using plotly in R to show "facets! interactively in dropdown list

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, facet, gganimate

I'd like to create an animated graph using plotly in R in a way in which my facets are displayed by selectiong on a dropdown list. I'm not sure if this can be done, I have seen something similar [here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Espietrzyk/96/drop-down-menus-styling/#plot) but I've got around 30 different categories so doing the code one by one manually would take quite a lot of time...

Basically, my plots are line graphs showing timing (T0 to T8) of sightings of different species within different regions. I'd like to generate a graph in which I could select an Ecoregion and visualise lines showing the mean timing for each time point of a species in that region, that is one line per species present (no mater if there were 1 or 20 records) I've got the following graph

```
set.seed(123)
species <- rep(c("Species A", "Species B", "Species C"), each = 7)
ecoregions <- rep(letters[1:30], each = 2)  
times <- rep(0:7, times = 3)
values <- matrix(rpois(21, 10), ncol = 3)
colnames(values) <- paste0("DaSS", 1:3)

Df2 <- data.frame(Tpoint = rep(values, each = length(ecoregions)),
                  Time = rep(times, times = length(ecoregions)),
                  Species = rep(species, times = length(ecoregions)),
                  Ecoregion = rep(ecoregions, each = length(times)))
```

This is my ggplot code for creating what I want with facets, but since there are many ecoregions these are tiny, so I'd like to create an interactive plot with plotly instead of facets

```
p<-Df2%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Times, y = values, group =Species, color=Species)) +

  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "line")+
  #geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = TRUE) +
  
   labs(title = "Amount of time by species and ecoregion",
       x = "Time point",
       y = "hours")+
theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14),  # Adjust strip text size
        strip.background = element_blank(),    # Remove strip background
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")
) +facet_wrap("Ecoregion")
```

I've used something like the below code but haven't had much luck...the data won't change when I use any of the buttons.

```
p <- Df2 %>%
  group_by(Species, Ecoregion) %>%
  #summarize(mean_Time = mean(Time)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Species, y = ~Time, color = ~Species, type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Species"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Time"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(type = "buttons",
           showactive = FALSE,
           buttons = button_list)
    )
  )

# Show the interactive plot
p
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show definition of `button_list`.

Comment: To dynamically filter, you need to use `transforms`. See plotly [filter docs](https://plotly.com/r/filter/).

Comment: Perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364461/plotly-update-several-data-attributes-in-an-argument-with-r) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a `restyle` button list that contains the subset values by `Ecoregion` with all plot aesthetics (`x`, `y`, `color`, `type`, `mode`):

```r
button_list <- lapply(
  unique(Df2$Ecoregion),
  \(er) list(
    method = "restyle", 
    args = list(
      "y", list(subset(Df2, Ecoregion == er)$Tpoint),
      "x", list(subset(Df2, Ecoregion == er)$Time),
      "color", list(subset(Df2, Ecoregion == er)$Species),
      "type", "scatter",
      "mode", "lines"
    ), 
    label = subset(Df2, Ecoregion == er)$Ecoregion[1]
  )
)

p <- subset(Df2, Ecoregion == unique(Df2$Ecoregion)[1]) %>%
  plot_ly( 
    x = ~Time, y = ~Tpoint, color = ~Species, type = "scatter", mode = "lines"
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Ecoregion Line Plots",
    xaxis = list(title = "Time"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Tpoint"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        buttons = button_list
      )
    )
  )

p
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked allowing me to view data in the selected ecoregions, however there are a couple of issues, all buttons are permanently showing on the left, ios there a way I could have like an arrow or something that could open to a drop down menu? Second, the data looks a bit odd when using your code, I'll post a pic of how it should look and how it looks

Comment: See revamped answer using `restyle`. The odd look is due to using the *Species* as `x` and `color` attribute. Make sure your numeric ranges are on `x` and `y` with grouping factors as `color`. This answer uses your above posted reprex, `Df2` which repeats values across *Species* (so lines superimpose each other). You may need to adjust for actual data frame.

Comment: As the OPs data look odd, let us consider `gapminder` data.  In that only include 4 countries, namely, `mycountries <- c("India", "Iran", "Iraq", "Italy")`.  We can consider 3 items to display, say, `varnames <- c("lifeExp","pop","gdpPercap")`.  Now, `Df2 <- gapminder %>%  dplyr::filter(country %in% mycountries) %>% pivot_longer(cols = varnames, names_to = "Ecoregion", values_to = "Tpoint") %>% dplyr::mutate(Times = year, Species = country)`

Comment: Adjust the levels with `Df2$Species <- factor(Df2$Species, levels = mycountries)`.  Then your code produces the initial plot fine.  However, any selection from the dropdown list messes up the plot as only one line is visible. @Parfait, any thoughts?

Comment: @YBS, thank you for that reprex! I tried getting buttons to work to no avail. I also do not see a good use case of subsetting data frames for line plots in plotly in docs or forums. This strange behavior seems buggy but admittedly I do not know this package/API well. See this [pastebin reprex](https://pastebin.com/w3KiTkGZ) that can be a new SO question or an [Git issue](https://pastebin.com/w3KiTkGZ) for authors if it is indeed a bug!

Comment: @Parfait, I got it to work!  Dataframe set-up is key.

Answer (score 0):

As your data looks odd (too many values are the same), I will use gapminder data. I will only select 3 countries to demonstrate.  You need to adjust your dataframe this way to make it work for your use case. The key is to use `method = "update"` and make it `visible` in `updatemenus`. Try this

```
mycolors <- c("orange","dodgerblue","green")
mycountries <- c("France", "Italy", "Spain")
varnames <- c("lifeExp","pop","gdpPercap")

n <- length(mycountries)
m <- length(varnames)

cols <- c()
for (i in 1:m){
  for (j in 1:n){ cols[j + 3*(i-1)] <- paste0(varnames[i],"_",mycountries[j]) }
}

df <- gapminder %>%  dplyr::filter(country %in% mycountries) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = country,
    values_from = varnames
  )  %>%  select(all_of(cols),year)

## Add trace directly here, since plotly adds a blank trace otherwise
p <- plot_ly(df,
             type = "scatter",
             mode = "lines",
             x = ~year, 
             y= ~df[[cols[[1]]]], 
             line = list(color = mycolors[1]), 
             name = mycountries[1]) 
p <- p %>% add_lines(x = ~year, y = df[[2]], name =  mycountries[2], line=list(color = mycolors[2]), visible = T)
p <- p %>% add_lines(x = ~year, y = df[[3]], name =  mycountries[3], line=list(color = mycolors[3]), visible = T)

p
## Add arbitrary number of traces
## Ignore first 3 columns as it has already been added

coln <- 3
for (col in cols[4:9]) {
  print(col)
  coln <- coln + 1
  k <- coln %% 3
  j <- ifelse(k==0,3,k)
  #name = sub("\\_.*", "", col)  ##  varname
  name = sub(".*_", "", col)    ##  country name
  p <- p %>% add_lines(x = ~year, y = df[[col]], name = name, line=list(color = mycolors[j]), visible = F)
}

mytitle <- "Dropdown line plot"
data_var <- c("Life Expectancy","Population","GDP per Capita")

pp <- p %>%
  layout(
    title = paste(mytitle,"-",data_var[1]),
    xaxis = list(title = "Year"),
    yaxis = list(title = data_var[1]),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        # type="buttons",  ### prints all buttons; comment this line to get a dropdown
        ## Add all buttons at once
        buttons = lapply(0:(m-1), function(col) {
          list(method="update", 
               args = list(list(visible = c(cols == c(cols[col*3+1],cols[col*3+2],cols[col*3+3]))), # this defines visibility on click
                           list(yaxis = list(title = paste(data_var[1+col])), title = paste(mytitle,"-",data_var[1+col]) ) 
                      ),
               label = paste0(varnames[1+col])
               )
        })
      )
    )
  )

pp
```