# Dropdown menu in R plotly to plot subsample

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to use a dropdown menu to plot a subsample of a dataset using the dropdown menu from `plotly` in R.

This is what I have so far (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024029/plotly-updating-data-with-dropdown-selection)) without sucess:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

X <- data.table(xcoord = 1:10, ycoord = 1:10)
Z <- X[xcoord < 5]

gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x = xcoord, y = ycoord)) + geom_point()

ggplotly(gg) %>%
  layout(updatemenus = list(
    list(buttons = list(
      list(method = "restyle",
           args = list(list("x", list(X$xcoord)),
                       list("y", list(X$xcoord))),
           label = "X"),
      list(method = "restyle",
           args = list(list("x", list(Z$xcoord)),
                       list("y", list(Z$ycoord))),
           label = "Z")
    ))
  ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: had to use named lists instead.

```r
ggplotly(gg) %>%
  layout(updatemenus = list(
    list(buttons = list(
      list(method = "restyle",
           args = list(list(x = list(X$xcoord)),
                       list(y = list(X$xcoord))),
           label = "X"),
      list(method = "restyle",
           args = list(list(x = list(Z$xcoord)),
                       list(y = list(Z$ycoord))),
           label = "Z")
    ))
  ))
```